# Merging search terms from 2 separate input fields

Tags: javascript, jquery, search

So I have javascript code to prepend "tag:" or "vendor:" before every search term, but I wanted to hide that from the user, so I created a hidden input field to send the code but it's not properly prepending the "tag:" and "vendor:" before every word.  and instead inputs the entire string, then the search terms.

```
<form method="get" action="/search" id="search-home">
                <button type="submit" value="search"></button>
                <input type="hidden" name="type" value="product" />
                <input type="hidden" name="q" class="searchtext" />
                <input type="text" name="red" placeholder="Search"/>
            </form>

        <script>
        $(document).on('submit','#search-home',function(){
        var searchtext = $('.searchtext').val();
          $('.searchtext').val("tag:"+searchtext+"* OR vendor:"+searchtext+"*");
        });
        </script>
```

Here's what the Url looks like with the code
http://zzz.co/search?type=product&q=tag%3A*+OR+vendor%3A*&red=tote#fullscreen=true&search=home

Here's what it's supposed to look like.
http://zzz.co/search?type=product&q=tag%3Atote+OR+vendor%3Atote#fullscreen=true&search=home

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're getting an empty value and inserting it here:

```
$(document).on('submit','#search-home',function(){
    var searchtext = $('.searchtext').val(); // <- HERE
    $('.searchtext').val("tag:"+searchtext+"* OR vendor:"+searchtext+"*");
});
```

What you should be doing is getting the user given query, which is the input you named "red".

```
$(document).on('submit','#search-home',function(){
var searchtext = $('input[name="red"]').val();
  $('.searchtext').val("tag:"+searchtext+"* OR vendor:"+searchtext+"*");
});
```

With the above fix, your URL will look similar to:
`http://zzz.co/search?type=product&q=q=tag%3Atote+OR+vendor%3Atote&red=tote`.

I do not know where you're getting your hashbang(`#`) from, but I would assume it will append at the end as before.

If you want to get rid of the `red=tote` part, you have a few options. Emptying the value via `$('input[name="red"]').val('');` will make it appear in your url as `red=`. If you want it gone entirely, you should use `$('input[name="red"].remove();`.

I would also advise having your "on" hook attached to the form, not the entire document. This is just a good practice to avoid using unnecessary resources as this hook will bubble every time a form is submitted, regardless of the selector. Instead, consider:

```
$('form#search-home').on('submit', 'button[type="submit"]', function() { ... };
```

That way it will only bubble when a submit event happens on that specific form, greatly reducing the possible instances those resources are used.